# Windows service of OpenPop exit from GetMessage code, same code OK win app

Tags: c#, windows-services, openpop, gmail-pop

We are implementing the code of downloading the attachment of Gmail A.C using

openpop3 namespace. In this code we are checking the attachment size if attachment

size is greater than specify value (value set in config file in kb).then it has to

send email to sender ....
                It works fine in windows application but whenever I implement code

in Window service it is getting a problem. It exit function from this line of code

```
OpenPop.Mime.Message m = popClient.GetMessage(i);
```

Framework:3.5
V.S:2008
Language#
Open POP namespace V2.0.4.369

```
This is my code

 OpenPop.Mime.Message m = popClient.GetMessage(i);


private void ReceiveMails()
    {

            Utility.Log = true;
            if (popClient.Connected)
            {
                popClient.Disconnect();
            }
            popClient.Connect(POPServer, port, ssl);
            popClient.Authenticate(username, password);
            int Count = popClient.GetMessageCount();
            writeToLogFile("Total Mail count is:" + Count.ToString());
            if (Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= Count; i++)
                {
                    flag = false;

                    OpenPop.Mime.Message m = popClient.GetMessage(i);
                    Sub = m.Headers.Subject;
                   int size = popClient.GetMessageSize(i);
                    int mailsize = int.Parse(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings

["emailSize"]) * 1024;



                    if (size < mailsize)
                    {
                    //we are checking the sub of Email
                    for (int j = 1; j < 30; j++)
                    {

                        strFranchisekey = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings

["Franchise" + j];
                        if (strFranchisekey != "")
                        {
                            int inex = strFranchisekey.IndexOf("=");
                            strFranchiseshortvalue = strFranchisekey.Substring

(0, inex);

                            if (Sub.Contains(strFranchiseshortvalue))
                            {
                                flag = true;

                                foreach (OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart attachment in 

m.FindAllAttachments())
                                {
                                    writeToLogFile(attachment.FileName);
                                    file = attachment.FileName;
                                    index = strFranchisekey.IndexOf("=");
                                    string StrCity = strFranchisekey.Substring

(index + 1);
                                    strFolderPath = 

(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FolderPath" +StrCity]);
                                    StrSubFolderPath = 

(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SubPath" + StrCity]);
                                    if (Directory.Exists(strFolderPath))
                                    //we are checking folder exists or not ?
                                    {
                                        File.WriteAllBytes(strFolderPath + "\\" 

+ file, attachment.Body);
                                    }
                                    //
                                    else if (Directory.Exists

(StrSubFolderPath))
                                    {
                                        File.WriteAllBytes(StrSubFolderPath + 

"\\" + file, attachment.Body);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //we can give here invalid path.
                                        File.WriteAllBytes

(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["InvalidPath"] + "\\" + file, attachment.Body);
                                        sendEmail(i);

                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    if (flag != true)
                    {
                        writeToLogFile("matching franchise name is not found");

                        foreach (OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart attachment in 

m.FindAllAttachments())
                        {
                            File.WriteAllBytes

(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["InvalidPath"] + "\\" + file, attachment.Body);

                        }
                        sendEmail(i);
                    }

                }
             }
    else
  {
     writeToLogFile("Please reduce the  email size");
   }

            }
            else
            {
                writeToLogFile("No New Attachment");
            }



        }
```

Comment: It probably throws some exception, could you post exception ?

Comment: @Antonio Bakula Thanks 
           In this code we have not written any try catch block but I am sure this code is not throwing any exception.because if it throws any exception then service will stop. But service is not stopping at all it is running continuously.
                    When we attach up to 500kb file. It works fine. But over 500kb it won’t download the attachment and exit from the function.
                   We wrote a log file. It goes up to this line code (OpenPop.Mime.Message m = popClient.GetMessage(i);)
 And exit from the function. let me know if u have any suggestions

Comment: well I really don't know any other reason for exiting other that exception, so I think that you really should try to catch exceptions and log it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Antonio Bakula I wrote try catch block in my windows service app and logging it. Then I understood my bug and it gave exception, can't read message another instance is already reading. This was because the code is timer-based and

I was firing event after every 1 minute. Now I added code to stop timer as soon as it starts email processing and start timer once it finishes email processing code.